# Вычислить возраст по дате рождения в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Имеется дата рождения:

```
# Дата рождения
$date_birth = $request->birthday;

# Получаем текущую дату
$now = Carbon::now();
```

Как вычислить возраст? Пробовал так, но не работает:

```
$interval = $now->diff(Carbon::now($date_birth));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предельно просто:

```
$age = Carbon::parse($request->birthday)->diffInYears();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$birth = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y','25.02.2002');
dd($birth->diffInYears(Carbon::now()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Carbon::parse($birthday)->age;
```